# maximum number if requests per TCP connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I am acting as server which receives multiple requests from client in socket and handles in a thread.

Should i set any parameter in TCP level to set maximum number of requests a connection can handle simultaneously?
because in my server side ,if  processing the request is slow i observe that other requests are queued up (client says  request has been sent but i receive it late)

Kindly guide me

Comment: There is no maximum, and you can't set one, and it wouldn't solve your problem if you could. Requests per connection are sequential, and your problem is concurrency, or rather the lack of it. You need to handle each client socket in a separate thread.

Comment: i am handling the request in multi threaded fashion only.requests keep coming in sequentially in a persistant TCP connection established?.will it wait for response until it sends me next request or is it independent of weather i sent response for previous request.

Comment: If you are already 'handling [connections or] requests in a multi-threaded fashion' it is difficult if not impossible to see what your question is actually about. How your clients may behave over an established connection has absolutely nothing to do do with setting a maximum number of requests per connection.

Answer (score 1):

If it takes a long time to do the work and you want to handle multiple connections simultaneously, you have to change how you do things.

If you are actively using a lot of CPU during processing a long request, you'll need multiple threads.   That's the only way to actually get more CPU time / second -- assuming you have multiple cores available.

If you are waiting on things like file IO, then you can instead use asynchronous processing to handle the requests on a single thread, but just handle a little piece at a time.

Setting a maximum number of TCP connections won't help you handle more processes more quickly.  It will just reject connections and not even allow a first-come first-served type of behavior - it will just be random if a specific client ever gets through or not.

Comment: Currently i am handling request in multiple threads only.But still i see queuing whenever DB utilization is high in my side.Say usually it takes 1 second to process the request  and i do not face any issue.But if processing takes around 3-4 s client says they are not receiving response on time.timeout is 25s but.I am processing and sending in 4 s.where does the request lie so far.getting queued up?

Comment: if your database is too slow, the you need to speed it up.   Whether you want your clients to time out or get rejected connections doesn't matter much.   If you're saturating your database, maybe you don't want to accept as many connections, but there are many ways to solve it.  But tuning TCP connections is probably the wrong approach.